# How to change class based on if else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Within the header of my site I have a main navigation built using  Each hyperlink item contains a unique data-attribute that I am using in order to determine what content gets displayed via load().

My question is, how can I write an if else statement (assuming this is best method) to check the loaded content against the main navigation. For example, the loaded content will contain a wrapped div with an ID that matches that of the data-attribute for the clicked link in the header. What I am trying to achieve is a statement that will give the main navigation hyperlink unique class if it's data-attribute is equal to the ID of the loaded content.

```
<header id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="external.html" data-section="intro">intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="external.html" data-section="interactive">interactive</a></li>
        <li><a href="external.html" data-section="portfolio">photography</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

If for example the first link is clicked, a div with the id="intro" from within the external.html document gets loaded into the page. In this scenario, the html would show a hyperlink with a data-section = "intro" and also a div with an id ="intro".

I would like to know how I can write a binded (since the content is being loaded via .load() I assume I need to bind the statement) if else statement in jquery to give the header navigation item that has a data-section value that matches a div's id value a unique class i.e, "active"

Example of loaded content when first link is clicked

```
<section id="intro" class="clearfix">
    <div>
        <h1>Bigger Thinking</h1>
        <h2>It’s what I aim to do on every project, big or small, rich or poor</h2>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var id = $('section').attr('id');
$('#header a').removeClass('unique')
$('#header a[data-section="'+ id +'"]').addClass('unique')
```